# Job Offered in UK - is it legit?

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens, job-hunting

I am USA Citizen and a guy from Texas.  Simple minded in all my days in a complex profession.  would have preferred to be a Farmer!
I have traveled to many Countries over the years but primarily on vacation.  I worked in UK years back but all pay was handled within USA, my assignment was temp in England.

I have alleged job offer from older company in UK.
I cannot find much on Maple Energy UK via Google as they are shown to have gone broke about 2015.  Now bankruptcy is common place in oil business these days.   The biggest companies are struggling many ways even.
Of course this company may be on the re-bound and I could be part of the come back along with other efforts of course.

This company has referred a Solicitor/Attorney to me to prepare Work VISA in UK.
This Solicitor has sent me some Immigration forms to fill out that has some info required typically one doesn't let out so easy such as my birth-date and info regarding my Parents.  They also want me to send them a Passport Pic for an ID accompanying the VISA request.

This whole deal seems a bit shady so what to worry about?

Comment: Have you looked up the solicitor? If they are real, you should be able to find out about them, and they are subject to significant ethics rules.

Comment: You could try [looking up the solicitor](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/) with the Law Society to see if the contact information they provide is legitimate, but this is almost certainly a scam intended to steal your personal information for identity theft. No company makes unsolicited job offers to random people; this should be common sense.

Comment: Chooster---Well, it is not an un-solicited job offer.  It is a job I applied for via reputable internet job board.  I am not a dumb teenage hick really.  Thanks.

Comment: Patricia- Thank you very much.  Looking into this via Link you provided.

Comment: Patricia, I could only search by Post Code.  That has 2,573 reuslts.  I cannot enter the Solicitor by name to weed out all but the 1 I need to investigate?  Bummer.

Comment: The 'Find a solicitor' link sorts by how close to the postcode they are. If you enter the postcode of the solicitor's address, they should be in the first few. Also any decent law firm should have an online presence, which means a google search for the firm name and town it is in should turn them up. You can also ask for their Solicitor's Regulation Authority ID.

Comment: Theresa-Scrolled through 25 pages of Solicitors within 25 mile radius of their alleged Post Code.  Didn't see them but not so confident about my scrolling and scanning ya know.  Thanks so much for your valuable input.  any other suggestions?  I have contacted Family in UK to see what they might be able to scrape up as well but London is a Zoo and not my or my Family's idea of fun time place.

Comment: Also all the signs seem to be that Maple Energy went bankrupt in 2015. Bankruptcy in the UK is not usually like US 'chapter 11' bankruptcy, which is a temporary thing - it usually means the company is toast. You should ask the solicitor for details of how the company came back, and for links to the company website and the company's registered address.

Comment: DJClayworth-Thanks.  The "Solicitor's Regulation Authority ID" is great info...Thanks.  That site refers to that as their SRA.  Of course this alleged Solicitor has a web site.  The site lists Immigration and VISAs as part of their practice.  Checked that out days ago.  The email on that site is same as I was contacted from.  With all that said, so what?  I can have a site hosted any name I want for about 10USD Month.

Comment: On the Law Society search page, the default is "Quick Search". There is also a f[ull search](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/?Pro=True) tab, or use the link in this comment. It lets you search by name, not just location.

Comment: Possibly try Glassdoor and LinkedIn. See if you can leverage your contacts.

Comment: Patricia- Thank you.  Previously I only saw one available way for me to search as the Pro Search not available to me(subscription req'd?).  Anyway, via your link this alleged Solicitor is not found.  Oh surprise, surprise.  So many scammers.  Makes job hunting very difficult today.

Comment: mkennedy-I think I originally applied for this "job" via Glassdoor.  Scammers are everywhere making it tough for the working folks.

Comment: @mkennedy glassdoor suggests that the company is headquartered in Dublin.  Can an Irish company hire employees in the UK without having a UK subsidiary?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the job qualifies as a Tier 2 general work visa, the first step is you must obtain a [Certificate of Sponsorship](https://www.gov.uk/uk-visa-sponsorship-employers). The UK keeps a [list of legal sponsors](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/626763/2017-07-11_Tier_2_5_Register_of_Sponsors.pdf). It doesn't look like Maple Energy is a licensed sponsor. If the company is not a licensed sponsor, this should raise red flags about what visa they are applying for on your behalf. You should ask then what name they are listed as a licensed sponsor under.

Assuming they are a licensed sponsor, they need some information from you to issue the COS. The COS must be [clearly yours](http://www.workpermit.com/immigration/united-kingdom/tier-2-visa-certificate-sponsorship) and *bear your name, age and other details as they appear on your passport*. As far as I can tell, that is all the information they need from you. A passport picture and information about your parents is definitely not needed for the COS.

Once the COS is issued, the visa application includes a lot more personal information. I would not provide anyone with this information until a COS is issued. If you are still feeling concerned, you can apply for a Tier 2 visa without their solicitor. You could either negotiate that they pay or simply pay for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are two currently trading companies which might be the one you applied to. Take a look at the UK government website 
https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=Maple+energy

Be aware it could still be a scam: don't drop your guard too soon.

Comment: One of them is a one-person company, one a husband-and-wife company, neither has ever filed any income. I would bet that neither of them is trying to hire someone from the USA

Comment: @gnasher729 searching the web suggests that there is a more substantial company by that name in Dublin.